# Heroku-Not Found (Python)

Tags: python, heroku, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

As a beginner, I just can't get any further.
I am trying to load a python program on heroku, but somehow only the following will always appear:

## **Not Found**

### The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

My logs:

```
2018-02-12T11:33:54.658010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `python app.py`
2018-02-12T11:33:56.853591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to up
2018-02-12T11:33:56.619420+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting app on port 50619
2018-02-12T11:33:56.661819+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on 
http://0.0.0.0:50619/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2018-02-12T11:34:48.437183+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.5.180.220 - - [12/Feb/2018 
11:34:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2018-02-12T11:34:48.445571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
path="/" host=protected-citadel-58416.herokuapp.com request_id=e8d60622-
5acd-4ddf-9b98-87307b1266b7 fwd="79.213.120.187" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 
service=29ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2018-02-12T11:40:15.749446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" 
host=protected-citadel-58416.herokuapp.com request_id=8e5c9f8e-c750-48bd-
a8ae-d40e7d3ea1d6 fwd="79.213.120.187" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms 
status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2018-02-12T11:40:15.743311+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.79.228.240 - - [12/Feb/2018 
11:40:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2018-02-12T11:40:57.718508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" 
host=protected-citadel-58416.herokuapp.com request_id=312900cd-79d6-4f9c-
9c5b-a40d356219bb fwd="79.213.120.187" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms 
status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2018-02-12T11:40:57.712039+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.79.228.240 - - [12/Feb/2018 
11:40:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

My program (a dialogflow webhook, could also be the problem):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from future.standard_library import install_aliases
install_aliases()

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode, quote_plus
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import json
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = processRequest(req)

    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    # print(res)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r


def processRequest(req):
    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))
    if req.get("result").get("action") == "getpassword":
         baseurl = "http://www.passwordrandom.com/query?command=password&format=json&count=1"
         if yql_query is None:
             return {}
         yql_url = baseurl 
         result = urlopen(yql_url).read()
         data = json.loads(result)
         res = makeWebhookResult(data)
    else:
        return {}
    return res

def makeWebhookResult(data):
    query = data.get('queryresult')
    if queryresult is None:
        return {}

    password = query.get('char')


    # print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))

    speech = "Your new password is " + password

    print("Response:")
    print(speech)

    return {
        "speech": speech,
        "displayText": speech,
        "data": {...},
        "contextOut": [...],
        "source": "WolframAlpha"
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print("Starting app on port %d" % port)

app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

My Procfile:

```
web: python app.py
```

My requirements.txt:

```
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
flake8==3.5.0
Flask==0.12.2
future==0.16.0
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
pew==1.1.2
pipenv==9.0.3
psutil==5.3.1
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance

[This is my template](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-weather-python/blob/master/app.py)

## UPDATE

The code has been changed as suggested.

Log:

```
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069747+00:00 app[web.1]: Request:
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069877+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069880+00:00 app[web.1]:     "id": "14fe0cb2-ce54-48cd-9569-87fc55b6cacc",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069882+00:00 app[web.1]:     "timestamp": "2018-02-12T15:12:38.929Z",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069884+00:00 app[web.1]:     "lang": "en",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069885+00:00 app[web.1]:     "result": {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069886+00:00 app[web.1]:         "source": "agent",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069887+00:00 app[web.1]:         "resolvedQuery": "make a password",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069889+00:00 app[web.1]:         "speech": "",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069890+00:00 app[web.1]:         "action": "getpassword",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069891+00:00 app[web.1]:         "actionIncomplete": false,
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069892+00:00 app[web.1]:         "parameters": {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069894+00:00 app[web.1]:             "passwordlenght": ""
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069895+00:00 app[web.1]:         },
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069896+00:00 app[web.1]:         "contexts": [],
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069897+00:00 app[web.1]:         "metadata": {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069898+00:00 app[web.1]:             "intentId": "f46eb1ca-e0e3-428f-8442-8e6327b935d7",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069900+00:00 app[web.1]:             "webhookUsed": "true",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069901+00:00 app[web.1]:             "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069902+00:00 app[web.1]:             "intentName": "GeneratePassword"
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069903+00:00 app[web.1]:         },
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069904+00:00 app[web.1]:         "fulfillment": {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069906+00:00 app[web.1]:             "speech": "The service is currently not aviable.",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069907+00:00 app[web.1]:             "messages": [
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069908+00:00 app[web.1]:                 {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069909+00:00 app[web.1]:                     "type": 0,
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069911+00:00 app[web.1]:                     "speech": "The service is currently not aviable."
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069913+00:00 app[web.1]:                 }
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069915+00:00 app[web.1]:             ]
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069916+00:00 app[web.1]:         },
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069918+00:00 app[web.1]:         "score": 1.0
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069919+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069921+00:00 app[web.1]:     "status": {
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069922+00:00 app[web.1]:         "code": 200,
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069924+00:00 app[web.1]:         "errorType": "success",
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069925+00:00 app[web.1]:         "webhookTimedOut": false
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069927+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069929+00:00 app[web.1]:     "sessionId": "dbb472ca-cd7d-4c03-b666-66d90b458f22"
2018-02-12T15:12:39.069934+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2018-02-12T15:12:39.341869+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.77.75 - - [12/Feb/2018 15:12:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2018-02-12T15:12:39.344514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=protected-citadel-58416.herokuapp.com request_id=842f0891-6768-48e9-a6d8-740b8dc4a8d6 fwd="35.202.154.33" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=275ms status=200 bytes=147 protocol=https
```

JSON from dialogflow:

```
{
  "id": "947ae098-542c-4208-b49a-eed69fb001fd",
  "timestamp": "2018-02-12T15:30:24.471Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "make a password",
    "action": "getpassword",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "passwordlenght": ""
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "f46eb1ca-e0e3-428f-8442-8e6327b935d7",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 290,
      "intentName": "GeneratePassword"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "The service is currently not aviable."
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "dbb472ca-cd7d-4c03-b666-66d90b458f22"
}
```

Comment: You need to provide much more information of what you did if you expect someone to help you with your issue. Copy/pasting logs is a good start, but clearly not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a route set for the `/` request, just for a POST to the `/webhook` path. It looks like you're trying to test it by hand by entering in the address to your browser - which won't really help you a lot.

Similarly, it looks like you haven't configured the webhook in Dialogflow to use the `/webhook` path. In the fulfillment section, you should set the URL for the full URL - including path. It might look something like this (note how it ends with /webhook):

```
https://YourHostNameHere:50619/webhook
```

You should be able to use a tool such as curl to hit the URL using a POST. You'll need to make sure it is via HTTPS and that you're sending JSON with a valid header. Possibly something like this

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://YourHostNameHere:50619/webhook
```

or, if you have the JSON in a file

```
curl -d "@file.json" -X POST https://YourHostNameHere:50619/webhook
```

You can also try through Dialogflow's test sidebar - if the pattern matches something that should be fulfilled through a webhook, it will send it there.

But this still may not quite work as you expect. It doesn't look like the return from `makeWebhookResult()` is valid JSON, which will confuse all sorts of things in your code and Dialogflow's.

**Update** to explain your code a little bit

These lines in your code:

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
```

very roughly say "I'm defining a function called `webhook()`. You should call this function when you get a POST request at the URL for this service that ends with the string `/webhook`."

So if you were hosting this at `heroku.example.com` on port 59123 using HTTPS, then the full URL for the webhook would be `https://heroku.example.com:59123/webhook`, and this is the URL you would need to enter this into the Dialogflow fulfillment page.

Your logs indicate you are calling this without the `/webhook` part. In particular, this line

```
2018-02-12T14:23:15.577096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=protected-citadel-58416.herokuapp.com request_id=b1b7e6d8-fd75-44e5-a2ab-1a73ea303f80 fwd="35.192.209.96" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=57ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
```

Suggests that, although it is being called at your host using HTTPS and POST, the path it is trying to route to is "/" rather than "/webhook".

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my code and included a link (my template). I tried to call it with the test sidebar, but it doesn't work. I couldn't quite understand your first suggestion for improvement.

Comment: Updated my answer - it looks like your fulfillment URL isn't correct for the same reasons - the URL should include the full route. In this case, that includes the "/webhook".

Comment: Updated again, this time with a longer explanation about what your code is asking for and what the logs are showing. (The other update is the second paragraph in the answer.)

Comment: I feel like we're almost there!
If I send a request via dialogflow, at least there will be no more errors!
Unfortunately, only the standard answer will be triggered and the answer I am trying to send will be completely ignored or will not arrive. What do I need to change? I added the JSON file.

Comment: I would restructure your code to see what the value of `req.get("result").get("action")` is. What you're reporting sounds like the `return {}` is what is being triggered. I'd focus your debugging there.