# Deploying Python&React to heroku

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, deployment

I am very new to python flask, please advise me. I have been trying to deploy my web app built with React and Flask and I have struggled.
I have googled around how to deploy but still can't deploy. What should I do..?

error message says no module named server.

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'

 [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

this is my work directory right now.

[image]

this is my server.py

[image]

this is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your project files out of the venv folder and into the main directory where your Procfile is stored.

Heroku is not finding `server.py` because it is not in the same folder as `Procfile`. The venv directory should not have your project code in it and should be reserved for package management purposes.

Comment: oh thank you, that worked. but i have another error saying: "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." I'm not quite sure what I need to do.

Comment: My guess is that you were trying to access the url `yourapp.herokuapp.com/` and not `yourapp.herokuapp.com/email`. [Similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745887/heroku-not-found-python). If this doesn't fix it, I'd suggest opening another question.